# Переключение на последнюю активную вкладку MaterializeCSS

Tags: jquery, tabs

Здравствуйте. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно после перезагрузки страницы оставаться на последней активной вкладке компонента Tabs в MaterializeCSS?

Пробовал так сделать, но, видимо, не в ту сторону думаю.

```
<script>
    function selectLastTab(tab) { $('ul.tabs').tabs('select_tab', tab); }
</script>";

<ul class="tabs">
    <li class="tab col s2" onclick="selectLastTab('t1')"><a class="active" href="#t1">T1</a></li>
    <li class="tab col s2" onclick="selectLastTab('t2')"><a href="#t2">T2</a></li>
    <li class="tab col s2" onclick="selectLastTab('t3')"><a href="#t3">T3</a></li>
</ul>
```

Выдает ошибку:

> jquery-2.1.1.min.js:2 Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size
>   exceeded

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сохраняйте текущее состояние в localStorage - https://jsfiddle.net/sqpbxuco/3/

```
$(function(){
    var current_tab = (localStorage || {}).tab || 'test1';
    $('ul.tabs').tabs({onShow:saveSelectedTab});
    $('ul.tabs').tabs('select_tab', current_tab);

  function saveSelectedTab(){
        var tab_id = $(this).attr('href').substr(1);
        (localStorage || {}).tab = tab_id;
   }

});
```